# Open notepad automatically when an USB is connected in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, autorun

I need to open notepad when a user connects an USB drive to the computer in windows 10.I'm using autorun.inf file which has the following code in it:

```
[autorun]
ShellExecute=notepad.exe
```

The code is giving the following error on execution of the above file:

[image]

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: you cannot have a normal usb drive set up in way that it will execute anything on connection to an arbitrary pc (autorun.inf stopped working during the time of win xp due to it being abused by viruses). Does this have to work on arbitrary pcs? It could very well be possible to set up some specific pcs to run a file once a usb drive is connected

Comment: I want it to run it on every PC. Anyhow thanks for the information that you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Autorun on USB stopped being available on win7 but I think it still works on CDs & DVDs. Put your autorun.inf and program on a CD to see if it works.
Use open=filename  or  shellexecute=filename